# IllegalStateException : Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to write code in eclipse java android to input two fields into a database. After a 3 rows of entries into the database, I click on "View list" database and I get an error. I have narrowed the error I think down to the in `DetailActivity.java`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RaceListActivity.class);
```

There exists a `RaceListActivity.class` and `RaceListActivity.java.` But I am getting this error.  `DetailActivity.java` and `RaceListActivity.java` code is below where the error exits from. The `LogCat` is below that.

**Detail Activity.java**

```
// Shows/edits the data for one row.
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {
    private RaceDB mDB;
    private Long mRowId;
    private EditText mEditText1;
    private EditText mEditText2;
    private CheckBox mCheckBox;
    private static final String TAG = "INFORMATION";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        mRowId = null;

        if (bundle == null) {  // initially, Intent -> extras -> rowID
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(RaceListActivity.EXTRA_ROWID)) {
                mRowId = extras.getLong(RaceListActivity.EXTRA_ROWID);
            }
        }
        else {  // tricky: recover mRowId from kill destroy/create cycle
            mRowId = bundle.getLong(SAVE_ROW);
        }

        mDB = new RaceDB(this);
        mDB.open();
        Log.d(TAG, "Database is now open and saved");
        dbToUI();
        Log.d(TAG, "Database is now able to be shown");
        onPause();
    }       

    public void view_races(View v){
        Log.d(TAG, "Database is now almost shown");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RaceListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mDB.close();
    }

    // Copies database state up to the UI.
    private void dbToUI() {
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor cursor = mDB.query(mRowId);
            mEditText1.setText(cursor.getString(RaceDB.INDEX_TITLE));
            mEditText2.setText(cursor.getString(RaceDB.INDEX_BODY));
            mCheckBox.setChecked(cursor.getInt(RaceDB.INDEX_STATE) > 0);

            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        save();
    }


    /** Save the state in the UI to the database, creating a new row or updating
     * an existing row.
     */
    private void save() {
        String title = mEditText1.getText().toString();
        String body = mEditText2.getText().toString();
        int done = 0;
        if (mCheckBox.isChecked()) done = 1;

        // Not null = edit of existing row, or it's new but we saved it previously,
        // so now it has a rowId anyway.
        if (mRowId != null) {
            mDB.updateRow(mRowId, mDB.createContentValues(title, body, done));
        }
        else {
            mRowId = mDB.createRow(mDB.createContentValues(title, body, done));
        }
    }

    public static final String SAVE_ROW = "saverow";
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putLong(SAVE_ROW, mRowId);
    }
}
```

**RaceListActivity.java**

```
// Main activity -- shows data list, has a few controls.
public class RaceListActivity extends ListActivity {
    private RaceDB mDB;  // Our connection to the database.
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "INFORMATION";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database is now shown");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_races);

/*        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startDetail(0, true);  // true = create new
            }
        });*/

        // Start up DB connection (closed in onDestroy).


        mDB = new RaceDB(this);
        mDB.open();

        // Get the "all rows" cursor. startManagingCursor() is built in for the common case,
        // takes care of closing etc. the cursor.
        Cursor cursor = mDB.queryAll();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        // Adapter: maps cursor keys, to R.id.XXX fields in the row layout.
        String[] from = new String[] { RaceDB.KEY_TITLE, RaceDB.KEY_STATE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.rowtext, R.id.rowtext2 };
        mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row2, cursor, from, to);

        // Map "state" int to text in the row -- intercept the setup of each row view,
        // fiddle with the data for the state column.
        mCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == RaceDB.INDEX_STATE) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                    if (cursor.getInt(RaceDB.INDEX_STATE) > 0) {
                        textView.setText(" (done) ");
                    }
                    else {
                        textView.setText("");
                    }
                    return true;  // i.e. we handled it
                }
                return false;  // i.e. the system should handle it
            }
            });

        // Alternative: also have row.xml layout with just one text field. No ViewBinder
        // needed for that simpler approach.

        setListAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        // Placing a clickable control inside a list is nontrivial unfortunately.
        // see bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414

    }

    // Placing this next to onCreate(), help to remember to mDB.close().
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mDB.close();
    }

    // Create menu when the select the menu button.
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.pref_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Called for menu item select. Return true if we handled it.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.prefs:
                // open prefs, previous lecture
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }


    // Create context menu for click-hold in list.
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
    }

    // Context menu item-select.
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_detail:
                startDetail(info.id, false);
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_delete:
                remove(info.id);
                return true;                
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    // Removes the given rowId from the database, updates the UI.
    public void remove(long rowId) {
        mDB.deleteRow(rowId);
        //mCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // confusingly, this does not work
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().requery();  // need this
    }


    public static final String EXTRA_ROWID = "rowid";

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long rowId) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, rowId);
        startDetail(rowId, false);
    }

    // Starts the detail activity, either edit existing or create new.
    public void startDetail(long rowId, boolean create) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        // Our convention: add rowId to edit existing. To create add nothing.
        if (!create) {
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ROWID, rowId);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
        // Easy bug: remember to add to add a manifest entry for the detail activity
    }
}


/*
Customizing how the data goes into each list/row (use with row2 layout)

        mCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == RaceDB.INDEX_STATE) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                    if (cursor.getInt(RaceDB.INDEX_STATE) > 0) {
                        tv.setText(" (done) ");
                    }
                    else {
                        tv.setText("");
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            });
*/
```

**LogCat**

```
12-02 22:37:47.785: D/INFORMATION(768): Database is now open and saved
12-02 22:37:47.785: D/INFORMATION(768): Database is now able to be shown
12-02 22:38:24.275: D/INFORMATION(768): Database is now almost shown
12-02 22:38:24.310: D/AndroidRuntime(768): Shutting down VM
12-02 22:38:24.310: W/dalvikvm(768): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  ... 11 more
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {edu.CIS2818.TriTracker/edu.CIS2818.TriTracker.RaceListActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at edu.CIS2818.TriTracker.DetailActivity.view_races(DetailActivity.java:62)
12-02 22:38:24.375: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  ... 14 more
</pre>
```

Comment: Have you declared RaceListActivity.java in manifest file?

Answer (score 2):

Don't call Activity life-cycle methods manually . as in your current code you are calling `onPause();` with in `onCreate` of Activity. so change your code as:

```
    mDB = new RaceDB(this);
    mDB.open();
    Log.d(TAG, "Database is now open and saved");
    dbToUI();
    Log.d(TAG, "Database is now able to be shown");
   /// onPause();  remove this method from here this 
                   //will called automatically by system
```

and make sure you have declared `RaceListActivity` Activity in Manifest as:

```
<activity android:name=".RaceListActivity" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about the manifest file. Imran - if I don't put in an onPause the Logcat gives me an error of "Unable to pause activity". Any clues ??

Comment: but why you are calling `onPause` within `onCreate`  . right why is you can call save(); instead of `onPause`  within `onCreate`  method

Comment: I honestly do not know why I call save() in onPause(). I picked this code off of someone else and am trying to customize it and learn for the my app database use. They had written the onPause call and the logcat gives me an error if I don't call the onPause() in the onCreate() call.

Comment: @JohnJohn : but he is not calling onPause() within onCreate() .Note he is calling save() method inside  onPause() for saving Edittext Values in database when your application is going to leave user focus means when another Application appear in front of your application when user is viewing or if user press back or home button

Comment: @JohnJohn : if you have still any doubt then tell me i will try to clear it

Comment: In my app the user really has no purpose to press back. I will have a separate home button with a layout which is already configured which I can bring in easy. I will update my manifest file with the splash/home screen later. Also, I have the app navigation to use menu buttons up top that aren't currently there. I just took a look at the database code to get an idea of how things would work. Probably not the best code to look at.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the RaceListActivity entry in your projects manifest file :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".RaceListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error is below:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
```

Have you declared your activity in the manifest within the `<application>` tag?

```
<activity android:name=".RaceListActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```